# Remove values from pie chart on the inner side of pie chart

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have the following data I want to build a pie chart on

```
categories=['organic','cpc','referral']
proportions=[40.5,5.8,36.9]
```

So I do:

```
fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
labels = [f'{x} {np.round(y / sum(proportions) * 100, 1)}%' for x,y in dict(zip(categories, proportions)).items()]
ax1.pie(proportions, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=False, startangle=90, rotatelabels=True)
ax1.axis('equal')
fig1 = plt.gcf()
fig1.set_size_inches(7, 7)
circle = plt.Circle(xy=(0, 0), radius=0.75, facecolor='white')
plt.gca().add_artist(circle)
```

I get the following with these redundant values on the inner side of the pie, how I can get rid of them? I need information on the outer side stay and on the inner side to be removed:

[image: pie chart]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace `autopct='%1.1f%%'` with `autopct=None`

Answer (score 1):

remove `autopct='%1.1f%%',` will do the trick